# Searching for a generalization of $|A \cup B| + |A \cap B| = |A| + |B|$.

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, measure-theory

Recently I was working through an exercise in Heil's "Introduction to Real Analysis" where I came upon an exercise I wished to demonstrate without invoking the Steinhaus theorem. My proof, as it stands now, relies on an "intuitive" generalization of the following identity for $A, B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{d}$ where $A, B$ are measurable:

$$|A \cup B| + |A \cap B| = |A| + |B|$$

Intuitively, it seems there should be a generalization of this identity in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ for a finite collection of measurable sets. I have attempted to write this out for the case of 3 sets in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, where I established a similar result, but I find it difficult to see what is going in terms of the combinatorics, therefore making it difficult for me to write out a general statement (which presumably could be proved inductively).

In particular, I am searching for some generalization of this result in $\mathbb{R}$ for finitely many sets. Any help or references would be particularly appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Comment: That's great, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting comments:

The general result is the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle):

$$\mu(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n A_k) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1}\left(\sum\limits_{I\in \binom{[n]}{k}}\mu(\bigcap\limits_{i\in I} A_i)\right)$$

Note the usage of index-set notation for superoperations like summation and unions, note that $[n] = \{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$, and note that $\binom{X}{k}$ with $X$ a set is the set containing all $k$-element subsets of $X$.

The three-set version for example reads:

$$|A\cup B\cup C| = |A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|A\cap C|-|B\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap C|$$

while the four-set version reads:

$$|A\cup B\cup C\cup D| = |A|+|B|+|C|+|D|-|A\cap B|-|A\cap C|-|A\cap D|-|B\cap C|-|B\cap D|-|C\cap D|+|A\cap B\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap D|+|A\cap C\cap D|+|B\cap C\cap D|-|A\cap B\cap C\cap D|$$

---

While this is typically used in combinatorics and typically used with regards to the counting measure, or in probability with regards to a probability measure, it can be seen to be true for generic finite measures as well with the caveat that extra care must be taken when infinite values are possible.

A typical approach to a proof would be to note that $A\cup B$ is equal as a set to $(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)\cup (A\cap B)$ and that this is a partition, as well as that $A = (A\cap B)\cup (A\setminus B)$.  Additivity of the measure then applies giving the result for two sets.

Using the result for two sets you can then extend to three and beyond using induction, noting that $A\cup B\cup C = (A\cup B)\cup C$ thanks to associativity.